# Migrate to AndroidX :: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-fragmentactivity, androidx

```
    //calling Activity written in kotlin but activity is 
    //not started and giving below-mentioned exception
```

> Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
>          Unable to find explicit activity class 
>          com.myApp.personal/com.myApp.personal.camera.CameraActivityKt
>          have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
    //while Registered in manifest file: 
   <activity 
   android:name=
   ".camera.CameraActivity"android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"/>



    try{ 
       File f = setUpPhotoFile(prefixString); mCurrentPhotoPath =
       f.getAbsolutePath();
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, CameraActivityKt.class);
       intent.putExtra(IConstant.PATH, mCurrentPhotoPath);    
       startActivityForResult(intent, actionCode); 
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
       e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

Comment: can you add your manifest? have you added this activity in manifest?

Comment: @VedprakashWagh not working already tried what link you have added

Comment: Manifest activity is `CameraActivity`. Exception about `CameraActivityKt`

Answer (score 0):

**I got the Solution Kotlin activity will called like this from a java class:**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra(IConstant.PATH, mCurrentPhotoPath);
 ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, actionCode);
```